# ESTA denied. Is it worth applying for visa?

Tags: visas, usa, esta

I’ve recently applied for an ESTA, it’s been refused due to me being stupid years ago. I have a caution for growing cannabis, and also a conviction for handling stolen goods .... it’s it even worth applying for the visa ?

It’s been a long life dream to go New York for my 40th birthday and I just don’t want to spend lots and not get a visa.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, this type of question doesn't fit here very well, both because there's far too little detail (How far in the past is "years ago?" How old are you? What level of criminal violation was "handling stolen goods?" What's your personal history since those troubles? Employment? Ties to the UK? etc. etc.) Then there's weighing how important your "life long dream" is. For some, it'd be worth any cost to pursue. Others may feel differently. In short: we have far too little information, and even with more info the answer will be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Refusing an ESTA means only that the authorities want to have a closer look at your background. Depending on the nature of the offences, and the time that has passed they may be disregarded if everything else is acceptable. The only way to know is to apply, but you risk being refused. It's also possible to apply for a waiver in some cases. For that you'd need a lawyer and that will push the cost up. Is this worth it? Only you can judge.

Comment: Maybe. What sentence did you receive for handling stolen goods? Did you commit either of these crimes when you were under 18? What were the specific offences in each case? If you aren't sure, get your [police certificate](https://www.acro.police.uk/police_certificates.aspx) and come back here; you'll need it to apply for the visa anyway.

Comment: If you ask this question in terms of the legal technicalities, it will be on topic.  Whether a criminal conviction is grounds of inadmissibility in the US depends on several factors. If you do ask a new question (or [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/152481/edit) this one), we'll therefore need to know the things that Michael Hampton asked about.